# Editing/Deleting without authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I need to build a website that does not require an account, but you are still able to post.

Every time you post, you will be asked to input your email.

You will receive an email with a URL that allows you to edit/delete your post. Only by accessing the URL from the email you will be able to modify the post.

How would you implement that? I was thinking of creating an editID for each post and attaching that editID as a get param to the URL.

When the user goes to the URL, I grab the post that belongs to that editID.

On the backend, editing/deleting is allowed only if the editID is send by the frontend.

What do you think / do you guys have any other ideas of implementing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a pain in the neck; would you really use a site like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "editId" parameter in the url is okay (eg. https://example.com?edit=editID).

You would have to make sure that that ID is not displayed in the frontend of the website, since then any user could modify any given post.

The editID could be a one way hash of the title, for example a SHA256 hash.

That hash would be then saved in the post's metadata. Then (for example with PHP) you would search for a post within your database that has that SHA256 hash.